# Can't install an app build from testflight after upgrading to iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, testflight, iphone-4

I have a big problem. I installed iOS 8.0.2 on my iphone 4s, and now try to install builds from testflight. I can install builds from 3 apps, but builds from one I can't. it asks me to install the build, I accept, and after nothing happens. I can't even install old builds which I have installed before upgrading.

I tried to reset my  all settings, but it didn't help. What else can I do ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I share your problem, but I'm not a big fan of the solution :-)

Comment: solution is solution:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my problem is solved.

I made backup to iCloud, after factory reset and reinstalled my last backup from iClouds. Now can install all my app builds :)